# Matlab: How to use a .dat file in Neural Network?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use a .dat file's data to create an RBF neural network and train it. But I don't know how to use it's columns as *input* and *target* data in the network.

This is an image of the file in matlab:
[train.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3HO.png)

I tried this:

```
fid = fopen('train.dat','r');
A = fscanf(fid, '%f');
C1 = textscan(fid,'%s%f%s%f');   %read the first line
nb_col = C1{4};                     %get the number of columns (could be set by user too) 

%read the remaining of the file
C2 = textscan(fid, repmat('%f',1,nb_col), 'CollectOutput',1);

fclose(fid);                     %close the connection
```

My question is what code should I write at the beginning to open the ***train.dat*** file and put it's first column into a vector (patterns) and it's third column in another vector (target)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work but you can try:

```
load train.dat
patterns = train(:,1); % If just first column
patterns = train(:,[1:2]); % If column 1 & 2 are the vector patterns
target = train(:,3);
```